# SQL Server: what will trigger execution plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

If I have statement

```
DECLARE @i INT;
DECLARE @d NUMERIC(9,3);
SET @i = 123;
SET @d = @i;
SELECT @d;
```

and I include actual execution plan and run this query, I don't get an execution plan. Will the query trigger execution plan only when there is `FROM` statement in the batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *simple* answer is you don't get execution plans without table access.

Execution plans are what the optimiser produces: it work out the best way to satisfy the query based on indexes, statistics, etc.

What you have above is trivial and has no table access. Why do you need a plan?

Edit:

A derived table is table access as per Lucero's example in comments

Edit 2:

"Trivial" table access gives constant scans, not real scans or seeks:

- `SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE 1=0`
- Lucero's examples in comments

Comment: Well, the following is just as trivial but it does produce a query plan: `SELECT v.d FROM (SELECT @d d) v;` (is there a "table access" in there?)

Comment: @Lucero: yes.  is a *derived* or *inline* table. So this is `SELECT v.d FROM MyDerivedTable v;` no matter how trivial.

Comment: Okay. While we are at it, do you know what the name for values like this is? `SELECT v.d FROM (VALUES (123)) v(d);`

Comment: @Lucero: the same. Note the plan is just a "constant scan" not proper table access ("index seek" etc)

Comment: @gbn, one last question, why do you say that a constant scan is not a real scan? The query plan for this gives a constant scan with 9 rows and a filter on it: `SELECT v.d FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) v(d) WHERE v.d<5;`

Comment: @Lucero: There are 9 constants. A real table could have 0, 9 or 99 at runtime. I don't know why the optimiser then filters: probably not worth short circuiting this for "trivial" access. Although, `...WHERE v.d > 21` removes the filter

Comment: @gbn - Might be clearer to use the term "contradiction detection" as a trivial plan is something else (as I'm sure you know!)

Comment: @Martin: I tend to use trivial wrongly  because I've forgotten some finer points. I dont use it day to day...

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by what will trigger execution plan? Also I didn't understand I include actual execution plan and run this query, I don't get an execution plan. Hope this link may help you.

1. [SQL Tuning Tutorial - Understanding
   a Database Execution Plan (1)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql-tuning-tutorial-1.aspx)

Comment: I mean that if I include execution plan into this query (pressing Ctrl+M) and run this query, I don't see execution plan for this query. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I think it is because of No Database objects used in the query. But you can see an Estimated Execution plan.

Comment: +1 I was going to point out that it does generate a plan that can be seen with `Ctrl + L`

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that a query plan is generated whenever a set-based operation needs to be performed.

Comment: Note: `SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE 1=0` gives a constant scan not a table scan. This is SET based but still behaves like your derived table examples

Comment: Right. But the question was when an execution plan is generated, and even if the plan has only a constant scan in it it still is an execution plan, no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need a from clause.

You can do like this

```
declare @i int
declare @d numeric(9,3)
set @i = 123

select @d = @i
from (select 1) as x(x)

select @d
```

And in the execution plan you see this

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(9,3),[@i],0)">
```